# Can a Cassandra partition key span multiple tables in one keyspace?

Tags: cassandra, batch-processing, cql, cassandra-3.0, partition

In this example, would the batch be single partition or multi-partition?

use logskeyspace;

CREATE TABLE Log_User(LogDay timestamp, UserId int) PRIMARY KEY (Day, UserId)

CREATE TABLE Log_Event(LogDay timestamp, EventId int) PRIMARY KEY (Day, EventId)

BEGIN BATCH

INSERT INTO Log_User(LogDay timestamp, UserId int) VALUES("2018-03-21 00:00Z", 10);
INSERT INTO Log_Event(LogDay timestamp, EventId int) VALUES("2018-03-21 00:00Z", 23);
APPLY BATCH;

Comment: I know in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10876 Patrick McFadin says " A single partition key on one keyspace.table." when referring to removing the batch_size_warn_threshold. However, when designing a data model for Cassandra the idea is to make tables based on queries, so it is often the case that one would want to batch insert into multiple tables with the same partition key to keep these queries consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different partitions. One is on table Log_User and the other is on Log_Event. Multi-partition can be across multiple tables or one single table. The important thing is that each distinct table+partition key combination can be in different nodes, which increases the burden on the coordinator in a batch.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your clarification. If we are using Murmur3Partitioner and the values are the same, can we safely conclude that the inserts are going to the same node, and further conclude that this does not burden the Coordinator?